# What does an open : function do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am looking at the wordpress core in [edit-comments.js](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.3/src/wp-admin/js/edit-comments.js).

On line 383 is says:

```
open : function (comment_id, post_id, action ) {
```

I have looked online and cannot find what `open :` means?

Comment: It defines method `open` belonging to some object

Comment: its just the name of an object property. The object in this case is `commentReply` it also has a `close`, `revert`, `toggle` etc...

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `open` is the name of an object's property, and `:` is used to define the value of given property.

```
var obj = {open: function() {}};
        // ^^^^ property name

var obj = {open: function() {}};
              // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Property value.
```

Comment: Thanks. So the variable is called `obj` and the object in that variable is called `open` ?

Comment: no, open is a property of the object that is stored in the variable obj.

Answer (score 0):

Those are all the events for commentReply (line 273)

init, open, close, toggle, revert,etc..